# Problema Moodle - conexión desde moodle mobile

Tags: webservice, moodle, moodle-api

Tengo una **plataforma moodle, versión 2.9.1** y quiero conectarme a ella desde la aplicación **moodle mobile**, me autentifica el usuario (y me crea el token) pero me da

> ```
> error conectando con el servidor
> ```

Tengo los **web services** activados con los protocolos **REST** y **XML-RCP**.
Con otra aplicación no oficial me indica el origen del posible error dándome el mensaje `siteinfo fetch failed` y en el informe del registro del usuario con el que intento autenticar (administrador) me indica que la función de los web services `'moodle_webservice_get_siteinfo'` ha sido llamada, así como el nuevo nombre de esta función `'core_webservice_get_site_info'`.

Todo parece indicar que algo falla al preguntar la información al servidor pero después de buscar y buscar y probar varias configuraciones que he leído por los foros no consigo encontrar la solución.

¿Alguien sabe donde puede estar el problema y su posible solución?

Comment: ¿Dices que te autentica el usuario y crea el token, pero tienes: "error conectando con el servidor"? ¿Esto puedes verlo en el mobile o donde?
Podrías indicar cual es la aplicación no oficial y lo que haces.

Comment: El error conectando con el servidor me aparece en la aplicación móvil Moodle Mobile, la otra aplicación no oficial es MDroid que tiene el mismo funcionamiento que la oficial pero te muestra un mensaje de estado de las peticiones y en esta es donde me sale el mensaje de **siteinfo fetch failed**

Answer (score 0):

Tras actualizar **Moodle** a la ultima **versión 3.2.2+** el problema de conexión con la **App moodle mobile** se soluciono y funciona correctamente.